# mvn clean package error: No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: java, maven, package

Getting below error while mvn clean package.I am compiling this on command line.

```
>mvn -f myapp/pom.xml clean package
```

This is my command and bellow is the error. can someone please help me with this

```
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\VaibhavNandkule\myapp\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.170 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-24T19:20:14+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project myapp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to change into the project directory and just use `mvn clean package` but this will not resolve the issue see Mathieu's answer...

Answer (score 4):

so i had the same issue and was finally able to resolve it. The problem was my ~/.mavenrc file was pointing to the wrong java path.I had defined my java_home to `JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8 
Type the command :   `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`.
It would show something like this

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
1.8.261.12 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
1.8.0_261 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Now the problem was defining `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` as the java path it was picking up this `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home` rather than `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home` .
Changing the path to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home` in mavenrc(or in your case where ever you have defined the java path) fixed this issue

Comment: I had the same issue in my mac, changing JAVA_HOME directly to "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home" will also work

Answer (score 4):

For Mac, Update the "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home" in bash_profile.

Execute the following command :

vi ~/.bash_profile

Update the JAVA_HOME

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home

. ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 3):

While setting the absolute path of the JDK in pom.xml works, this is not a portable way to set java. Your colleagues wont appreciate when you'll commit and push that pom.xml.

For Maven, you have to make sure that JAVA_HOME points to the root of the JDK.

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171"
```

Since your on Windows you may as well set this in the standard Environment Variables panel.

You can verify your configuration by running `mvn -version`:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\tools\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_232, vendor: Amazon.com Inc., runtime: C:\tools\java\jdk1.8.0_232\jre
Default locale: fr_CA, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: That make sense, Thanks Mathieu. I will try it definitely.

Comment: Great. Dont forget to set this as the answer to close this question.

Answer (score -2):

Finally, It worked for me. I have to add the below code in my pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\javac.exe</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```